# A common method in React/javascript to track execution time of all functions in a program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance

We have tried different options like performance.now() or new Date().getTime() to track the execution time of each function/method. But with these we need to explicitly mention them in each and every function to calculate time taken.

As we have lot of methods, it leads to repetitive code. Is there any way to have one common function that can track time taken for execution by each and every method in the program?

Comment: No. But I don't think reinventing [the browsers developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go down this route, you could explore the js event loop and watch the stack for how long frames stay on top of each other?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But we are looking for option similar to below-

var t0 = performance.now();

doSomething();   // <---- The function you're measuring time for 

var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

We need to log these details to measure the performance of all functions. If we can have a common wrapper or function to do so it would be helpful